# Make element appear before/after previous text?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Given this:

```
<h1>This is a test <small>It is</small></h1>
```

Is there any CSS I could apply to the `<small>` that would have it appear BEFORE, and ON THE PREVIOUS LINE, before "This is..."? `float:left; display:block;` doesn't get it before the content.

Answer (score 1):

In a relatively simple case like this, you can use positioning. Declare the heading as relatively positioned, set a suitable top padding on it, and make the `small` element “absolutely” positioned (i.e., positioned relative to its positioned ancestor, the heading). Example:

```
h1 { position: relative; padding-top: 1em; }
h1 small { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 1.3em; }
```

Note that when setting the padding, `em` denotes the font size of the `h1` element, whereas when declaring the height of the inner element, the `small` element, `em` denotes *its* font size, which is smaller. Hence `1em` vs. `1.3em`, even though the padding is meant to give room for the `small` element. You probably want to set font sizes on `h1` and `small` (say, `h1 { font-size: 150% } small { font-size: 80% }`) to get more predictable rendering, and then experiment with the `padding` and `height` values to get the appearance you like. This tuning will also depend on the font.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

HTML:

```
<h1 id="thisid">This is a test <small>It is</small></h1>
```

CSS:

```
#thisid:before {
content:"This is the content on the line above \A  ";
white-space: pre;
}
```

The :before pseudo element will make the stuff go before. Whereas the `\A` will make a space break.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pikk/ZL54q/

Comment: I can't declare all that content via CSS - each <h1> would have a different <small>, and to "copy" all that text in the css seems... overkill?